# how to include tiles definition attributes in an inserted page

Tags: jsp, struts, tiles

I have a tiles-defs.xml that has these definitions...

```
<definition name="masterLayout" path="/WEB-INF/tiles-layouts/globalLayout.jsp">
    <put name="pageTemplate" value="over-ride for each page" />
</definition>

<definition name="childLayout" extends="masterLayout">
    <put name="pageTemplate" value="/WEB-INF/tiles-layouts/child/layout.jsp" />
    <put name="title" value="page title" />
    <put name="metaKeywords"    value="" />
    <put name="metaDescription" value="" />
    <put name="body"            value="/child/pagebody.jsp"/>
    <putList name="list">
        <add value="title" />
        <add value="metaKeywords" />
        <add value="metaDescription" />
        <add value="body" />
    </putList>
</definition>
```

in globalLayout.jsp I have this working, but I won't always know what attributes the child definition has added to the page.

```
<tiles:insert attribute="pageTemplate">
<tiles:put name="title"><tiles:getAsString name="title" /></tiles:put>
<tiles:put name="metaKeywords"><tiles:getAsString name="metaKeywords" /></tiles:put>
<tiles:put name="metaDescription"><tiles:getAsString name="metaDescription" /></tiles:put>
<tiles:put name="body"><tiles:getAsString name="body" /></tiles:put>
```

Since the child definition won't always include the same attributes.   Is there a way to use the putList in the child definition to put the attributes into the child page's scope inside of globalLayout.jsp?   I've tried the following, but it fails

```
<%@ page import="java.util.Iterator" %>
<tiles:importAttribute />
<bean:define id="list" name="list" type="java.util.List" scope="page" />
<tiles:insert attribute="pageTemplate" ignore="true" flush="true">
    <%
    for ( Iterator it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
        String item = (String) it.next();
    %>
        <tiles:put name="<%=item%>"><tiles:getAsString name="<%=item%>" ignore="true" /></tiles:put>
    <% } %>
</tiles:insert>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

instead of trying to push the attributes down to a child layout, I pulled the child layout up into the scope of the parent layout.

```
<tiles:importAttribute name="pageTemplate" />
<bean:define id="pageTemplate" name="pageTemplate" />
<jsp:include flush="true" page="<%=pageTemplate%>"></jsp:include>
```

Answer (score 13):

With Tiles 2 you can now set `cascade="true"` on `put-attributes` in tiles. This will make them visible to nested child templates.

See *[here](http://tiles.apache.org/2.2/framework/tutorial/advanced/nesting-extending.html#Cascaded_attributes)*

Comment: interesting- I hadn't seen that before.  Unfortunately, my original question was about some old code written with Tiles 1.